# Intellij create scope from files differing in two branches

Tags: intellij-idea

An Intellij `Scope` can be used to restrict the files analysed during "Inspect Code".

**Question:** Is there a way to define a scope from the files that differ between two commits or between a commit (or branch) and the current working directory?

This would simplify finding problems freshly introduced in a feature branch and would be particularly helpful for old code bases where running the inspections over the whole project generates  too many unrelated findings.

Note that the Scope "uncommitted files" does not help a code review with several commits on a feature branch.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request for it, please feel free to vote:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145053/Run-inspections-for-the-scope-of-selected-commits